# Using multiple SQL queries

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-5, zeos

I  have done some searching and can't find a definitive answer to this one.

I am just getting into SQL so be gentle. Using D5, TNTUnicode, Zeos and SQLite3

I have a DBGrid with all the Account names in the tblAccounts showing.
I have a DBGrid with all the Folders in the tblFolders showing.

In the OnCellClick of the Accounts grid I have an SQL query

```
qryFolders.Close;
qryFolders.SQL.Clear;  // Not really needed as I am assigning the Text next - but :)
qryFolders.SQL.Text:=
  'SELECT Folder FROM tblFolders WHERE UPPER(Account)="FIRSTTRADER"'
qryFolders.ExecSQL;
tblFolders.Refresh;
```

In my application, nothing happens, I still have the full list of Folders visible.

In the SQL-Expert desktop **that line works fine** and displays only the two Folders associated with that Account. In that app it keeps displaying the full list of Folders

If I step through the OnCellClick it shows the correct Text etc.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is the connection (if any) between qryFolders and tblFolders? qryFolders presumably gets a new dataset (although I'm not sure about your query), but you refresh tblFolders.

Comment: `ExecSQL` is a method to execute `insert`/`update` or other SQL statements that return no cursors. `ExecSQL` over a `select` statement is useless, since you usually want to get the returning cursor.

Comment: Better explain what are you trying to accomplish ;)

Comment: qryFolders and tblFolders have the same DataSource. I am trying to accomplish what I described in the "In the SQL-Expert desktop" original post, when I click the Account in the dbgrid, I want only the Folders associated with that Account to be displayed. The SQL line works in the SQL-Expert desktop so why not in my app? IF ExecSQL returns no cursor, it would be helpful for you to give an example of what WILL return a cursor. Constructive comments help. :)

Comment: `ExecSQL`, as @jachguate says, is for DML/DDL statements or SQL statements that return no results (like `INSERT` or `UPDATE`). To retrieve a cursor (rows of data) from a `SELECT`, just use `qryFolders.Open;` instead.

Comment: @user2175495 my comments are constructive, and it is the other way round. The database is the one that returns (or not) a cursor. If you want to take that _cursor_ and retrieve data, use the `Open` method and not the `ExecSQL` one. That's on the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLQuery.ExecSQL) for all data access layers I know. I think a good practice is to read the documentation before asking questions here, so you may be more prepared to understand the answers and comments.

Comment: if you want some user to be notified about your comments, please use the @user notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to display a Master-Detail (Account as Master, Folder as Detail), so we start from here:

```
// connecting the grids
AccountsDataSource.DataSet := tblAccounts;
AccountsGrid.DataSource := AccountsDataSource;

FoldersDataSource := tblFolders;
FoldersGrid.DataSource := FoldersDataSource;

// retrieving the data
tblAccounts.Open;
tblFolders.Open;
```

That should reflect, what you already have. Now lets go to the Master-Detail.

*It should be obvious that all Query and Table Components have a valid Connection set, so I will left this out.*

First be sure, the Query is not active

```
qryFolders.Active := False;
```

Having a Master-Detail with a Query as Detail, we have to set the `MasterSource`

```
qryFolders.MasterSource := AccountsDataSource;
```

and after that we can setup the Query with parameters to link to the fields from MasterSource. Linking to the field `Account` in the MasterSource is done by using `:Account`

```
qryFolders.SQL.Text := 
  'SELECT Folders FROM tblFolders WHERE UPPER( Account ) = :Account';
```

Now, we are ready to retrieve the data

```
qryFolders.Open;
```

Until this, we will not see any changes in the `FoldersGrid`, because we didn't told anyone to do so. Now let's get this to work with

```
FoldersDataSource.DataSet := qryFolders;
```

In your approach, you didn't `Open` the Query and you didn't link the Query to the Grid.

---

Another option is to have a Master-Detail without a separate Query.
(It seems there were some code refactoring, so i guess this is a working sample)

```
tblFolders.MasterSource := AccountsDataSource;
tblFolders.MasterFields := 'Account';
tblFolders.LinkedFields := 'Account';
```

Reference:

- [SourceForge ZTestMasterDetail.pas](http://sourceforge.net/p/zeoslib/code-0/2209/tree/trunk/test/component/ZTestMasterDetail.pas) (see line 181ff)
- [SourceForge ZDataset.pas](http://sourceforge.net/p/zeoslib/code-0/2209/tree/trunk/src/component/ZDataset.pas)

Comment: Wow, Sir Rufo, thanks for the great detail. I REALLY appreciate that. I had played with the Master Detail thing some time back but gave up in frustration. With this outline I am sure I will be well on the road. Thanks so much for taking the time.

Comment: You are welcome. Appreciating on SO works with upvoting and if an answer satisfy your question you should accept it