# Receiving data from an SQL table in Delphi

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, tadoquery

I have a form which needs to fetch and display data from a MYSQL database.
The SQL code which I have written works fine, as I have tried to execute it within MYSQL.

I have also used a similar format of code to the one in my form, within another form, to fetch and display SQL data. The code works perfectly in the other form.
However, my code for this form does not seem to be receiving/displaying the data from the SQL table.

Here's a snippet of the code written for the `OnShow` event of the form.

```
procedure TfrmEditBooking.FormShow(Sender: TObject);  
var  
  CustName: string;  
begin  
  if SelectedID > 0 then  
  begin  
    with frmBookingData.ADOQuery1 do  
    begin  
      Open;    
      SQL.Clear;  
      SQL.Add('SELECT Name, Surname ' +
              'FROM customers_main ' +
              'WHERE customers_main.idcustomers_main ' +
              'IN ' +
              '(SELECT bookings_main.customers_main_idcustomers_main ' +
              'FROM bookings_main ' +
              'WHERE bookings_main.idbookings_main = ' + IntToStr(SelectedID) + ')');
      ExecSQL;  
      CustName := FieldByName('Surname').AsString + ' ' + FieldByName('Name').AsString;  
      Label1.Caption := CustName;  
      Close;  
    end;  
  end;  
end;
```

Comment: You open the query, then change the opened query statement, then Execute that and finally closing. You should read how to use TADOQuery/TDataSet properly

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552718/using-multiple-sql-queries/15554868#15554868 is very similar to yours

Comment: Where do you set the connection string ?

Comment: Using a `ADOConnection` linked to my `ADOQuery`

Answer (score 1):

One uses 'execsql' when one is not expecting to receive a cursor into a dataset (in other words, use 'execsql' with 'update', 'insert' and 'delete' statements but not with 'select').

You should replace the 'execsql' command with 'open' ... and remove the 'open' before 'sql.clear'.

Don't use a subquery when you should be using a join.

I think that your code ought to look like this

```
procedure TfrmEditBooking.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if SelectedID > 0 then
  with frmBookingData.ADOQuery1 do
   begin
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add ('SELECT Name, Surname ');
    sql.add ('FROM customers_main inner join bookings_main');
    sql.add ('on customers_main.idcustomers_main = ');     
    sql.add ('bookings_main.customers_main_idcustomers_main');
    sql.add ('where bookings_main.idbookings_main = :p1');
    sql.params[0].asinteger:= SelectedID;
    open;  
    Label1.Caption := fieldbyname ('name').asstring + ' ' +
                      fieldbyname ('surname').asstring;
    Close;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it still doesn't seem to work. I now have:  
`Sql.Clear`, `Sql.Add`, `Open`, `FieldByName`, `Close`

Comment: @Babah254: I don't know whether you can use a subquery within an IN statement. Normally, you would write the literal values that idcustomers_main can hold, eg select name, surname from customers_main where idcustomers_main in (12,13,14). What does that subquery return? You can also remove the 'custname' assignment by writing Label1.Caption := fieldbyname ('surname').asstring + ' ' + fieldbyname ('name').asstring.

Comment: The SubQuery isn't the point here, but **reusing** the ADOQuery1 - looks to me as if this is already used

Comment: Yes, `IN` accepts a subquery, this is per standard and most, if not all, SQL products (at least, MySQL *is* among them) support that. However, @Babah254, why don't you enclose the entire method's body or, at least, the part starting from `SQL.Clear;` and ending with `Close;` in a `try/except` block? That would probably help you to establish the actual issue (i.e. you would see if it is with the SQL script or with how you call it or, perhaps, with the connection).

Comment: @Babah254: do you have a way of checking your query elsewhere (in an SQL command line or something similar)? First check that your query actually returns the data that it is supposed to; then put the query into your form.

Answer (score 0):

To get this running you should change it to

```
procedure TfrmEditBooking.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  CustName: string;
begin
  if SelectedID > 0 then
    begin
      with frmBookingData.ADOQuery1 do
        begin
          Close; // close first
          SQL.Clear;
          SQL.Add(
            'SELECT Name, Surname '+
            'FROM customers_main '+
            'WHERE customers_main.idcustomers_main '+
            'IN '+
            '(SELECT bookings_main.customers_main_idcustomers_main '+
            'FROM bookings_main '+
            'WHERE bookings_main.idbookings_main = '+IntToStr(SelectedID)+')');
          Open; // open the query
          if not Eof then
            CustName := FieldByName('Surname').AsString+' '+FieldByName('Name').AsString
          else
            CustName := 'not found';
          Close; // close when finished
        end;
      Label1.Caption := CustName;
    end;
end;
```

But you should get some (negative) side effects, if `frmBookingData.ADOQuery1` is already in use for something different

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. I have checked the link you sent in your other post. I am using the same `ADOQuery` for another routine, however, it is not executing anything at the time of the `frmEditBooking` `onShow` event occurring. I have tried to add another `ADOQuery` onto the form, however this does not work either.

Comment: Please describe "this doesn't seem to work". Do you get an Exception? Is this method assigned to the OnShow event? Use the debugger to examin if this method is called and what is done

Comment: I don't get an exception, I get no change to my labels caption. I do know the label is not the problem, as it has changed using other methods. It is not being used for anything but the SQL Query in hand at the moment. The method is called on the `OnShow` event of my `Edit` form. The ADOQuery, Connection and DataSource are all found on the `Data` form. I use an ID (SelectedID) which changes depending on what ID is clicked on, on my `Main` form. This ID is being passed correctly, as I have another label to prove this. I need my form to Display the customer's name according to their ID.

Comment: I'll step through the Debugger and let you know if I find anything